# Memory usage in cloud sql is very high

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We are using cloud sql mysql 8.0.18 in gcp , the total memory of the instance is 20gb , 18.5 gb is the limit and the current utilization is nearly 17.5 gb due to which our database instance keeps getting crash.

In one month it has crashed 3 times.

Why my db instance RAM utilization is high , Is there any solution of this scenario.

vCPUs :- 8 ,
Memory :- 20gb ,
SSD storage - 410gb

[image]

Comment: Did you review the query ran on your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: hi @WilsonHauck i am sharing you a link which contains the output of the query you provided https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RLWQVoCfHpQ1mSjxUFj4TTupTt5-GJ-Z?usp=sharing

Comment: what ever troubleshooting you do for onpermises,applies to  this cloud as well,review queries,see whats consuming memory

Comment: @NiteshMandal  Analysis in process.  Will try to have suggestions to you within 48 hours.

Comment: @NiteshMandal Your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS indicates com_create_table count of 3,018,904 in less than 4 days.  Averages 35,000+ tables per hour created.  Since your count of tables was 14,602 for your entire system, why are so many tables created?  What is your location country and time zone?

Comment: @WilsonHauck where did you see 3,018,904 , I am not able find this value in any of my shared page.

Comment: It was listed in the xlsx on the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS sheet posted a few hours ago.

Comment: The items are in alphabetical order.

Comment: I picked it up from the drive.google.com/drive/folders link of 9 hours ago.  In the SHEET named SHOW GLOBAL STATUS, near the top in alphabetical order.

Comment: okay @WilsonHauck got it

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck suppose we optimize our query which was making 35000+ per hour , If we reduce it to 50% would we see any drop in high RAM usage.

Comment: Who can possibly use 17,500+ new tables per hour?  Please post the complete query and EXPLAIN to go with it for analysis.  The suggestions provided will have a positive effect on reducing RAM usage and improve performance, if applied.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Google Cloud Database Flags (all dynamic today)

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 2048 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
read_rnd_buffer_size=32768  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 195,877
thread_cache_size=1024  # from 48 to reduce threads_created RPS > 3 
read_buffer_size-262144  # from 131072 to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 8,487
```

Please view profile for contact info.  Many more Global Variables need ajustment.

Observations

1. handler_rollback avg about 30 per day need to be prevented to conserve resources.
2. innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct of 90 (percent) would shorten 'warm up' delays.
3. select_scan RPS of 122 can be avoided with appropriate indexes and expedite query completion.
   Thanks for sharing your data.